# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long в чужой библиотеке

Tags: python, python-3.x, overflow

Использую `python 3.7`

На просторах [pip](https://pypi.org/) нашел библиотеку [eval7](https://pypi.org/project/eval7/) для определения покерных комбинаций и тому подобного. Решил опробовать код, приведенный в ридми.

```
import eval7
from pprint import pprint


deck = eval7.Deck()
hand = deck.deal(7)
deck.shuffle()
deck = eval7.evaluate(hand)
```

На что вывело такую ошибку

```
    from .equity import py_hand_vs_range_monte_carlo, py_hand_vs_range_exact, py_all_hands_vs_range
  File "eval7\equity.pyx", line 1, in init eval7.equity
  File "eval7\xorshift_rand.pyx", line 81, in init eval7.xorshift_rand
  File "eval7\xorshift_rand.pyx", line 78, in eval7.xorshift_rand.seed
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long
```

Судя по тому, что нарыл, такая проблема возникает из-за того, что питоновский `int` может быть любой длины, а сишный - нет.

**Вопрос**

Могу ли я как то исправить данную проблему, учитывая, что она возникает внутри самой библиотеки (то есть чтобы ее исправить нужно исправлять ее начинку?)

P.S. Данную, рекомендуемую библиотеку тоже установил `cython`

**Update**

`import eval7` такой код тоже не работает, то есть уже при импорте появляется данная ошибка.

Comment: а что можно сделать, если у вас кол-во комбинаций за 4 миллиарда улезает :)?

Comment: Попробовал в Google Colab, никаких ошибок не вышло. Там правда Python 3.6.9

Comment: Используете 32-битную версию Python (и, соответственно, версию библиотеки) или 64-битную?

Comment: Использую 64-битную @insolor

Comment: @Zhihar Такой пример использование был придуман не мной, так как это представлено в ридми, это должно работать